# Unable to Access Jupyter Notebook in Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, common-lisp

I'm trying to run a Jupyter Notebook inside a Docker container using a prebuilt image from Docker Hub, but I'm encountering issues accessing the notebook in my web browser. The specific Docker setup involves a Dockerfile, a Docker Compose YAML file, and a custom Jupyter configuration. Here are the contents of these files:

**Dockerfile**:

```
# Use the prebuilt Docker image from Docker Hub
FROM yitzchak/common-lisp-jupyter

# Copy the custom Jupyter configuration
COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /root/.jupyter/

# Set the working directory to /notebooks
WORKDIR /notebooks

# Start the Jupyter Notebook on container startup
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  common-lisp-jupyter:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: common-lisp-jupyter
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - notebook-data:/notebooks
    image: my-common-lisp-jupyter-image

volumes:
  notebook-data:
```

**jupyter_notebook_config.py**:

```py
# jupyter_notebook_config.py

c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
```

.

**Docker Logs: **

```
common-lisp-jupyter | [I 21:08:46.152 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/app/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
common-lisp-jupyter | [W 2023-09-27 21:08:46.987 LabApp] 'ip' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
common-lisp-jupyter | [W 2023-09-27 21:08:46.987 LabApp] 'ip' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
common-lisp-jupyter | [I 2023-09-27 21:08:46.997 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
common-lisp-jupyter | [I 2023-09-27 21:08:46.997 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/app/.local/share/jupyter/lab
common-lisp-jupyter | [I 21:08:47.003 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from the local directory: /notebooks
common-lisp-jupyter | [I 21:08:47.004 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:
common-lisp-jupyter | [I 21:08:47.004 NotebookApp] http://docker-desktop:8888/?token=4508beed261716fa50380308b533b9a2d19f190d0c9f9804
common-lisp-jupyter | [I 21:08:47.004 NotebookApp] or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=4508beed261716fa50380308b533b9a2d19f190d0c9f9804
common-lisp-jupyter | [I 21:08:47.004 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
common-lisp-jupyter | [W 21:08:47.010 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate a runnable browser.
common-lisp-jupyter | [C 21:08:47.010 NotebookApp]
common-lisp-jupyter | 
common-lisp-jupyter | To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
common-lisp-jupyter | file:///home/app/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1-open.html
common-lisp-jupyter | Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
common-lisp-jupyter | http://docker-desktop:8888/?token=4508beed261716fa50380308b533b9a2d19f190d0c9f9804
common-lisp-jupyter | or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=4508beed261716fa50380308b533b9a2d19f190d0c9f9804
```

Despite this setup, when I attempt to access the Jupyter Notebook using the provided URLs (e.g., `http://localhost:8888` or `http://127.0.0.1:8888`), I receive an error indicating that the web browser could not be found. I've checked my Docker Compose configuration and reviewed the logs, but I'm unable to resolve this issue.

Can someone please help me identify what could be causing this problem or suggest possible solutions?

---

Comment: what logs you get whan you open in browser url from docker logs 
http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=4508beed261716fa50380308b533b9a2d19f190d0c9f9804 ?

Comment: do you run docke container with jupiter and web browser in witch you open the url on same machine ?